# Как взаимодействовать c корневым Vuex файлом?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

Всем привет.
Есть такой код хранилища `index.js`:

```js
export const state = () => ({
  dbIndexData: null,
});

export const mutations = {

  init_data_for_index (state, uploadDbIndexData) {
    state.dbIndexData = uploadDbIndexData;
  },

};

export const actions = {
  async init_data_for_index2 ({commit, categories}) {
    commit('init_data_for_index', categories);
  },
};
```

И 1 страница + 1 компонент взаимодействующие с ним:

Главная страница:  index.vue

```js
<template>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <HeaderApp>
    </HeaderApp>

    <CenterContentIndexApp>
    </CenterContentIndexApp>

    <FooterApp>
    </FooterApp>

  </div>

</template>

<script>
  //index
  import axios from 'axios';
  import HeaderApp from '~/components/HeaderApp';
  import CenterContentIndexApp from '~/components/CenterContentIndexApp';
  import FooterApp from '~/components/FooterApp';

  export default{

  fetch ({ store, params }) {
    return axios.get('https://seo-gmbh.eu/json/api_sunds.php?action=get_pages&url=index')
    .then((res) => {
      store.dispatch('init_data_for_index2', res.data);
    })
  },


    components:{
      HeaderApp,
      CenterContentIndexApp,
      FooterApp,
    },

}

</script>
```

И входящий в нее компонент `CenterContentIndexApp`

```js
<template>

  <section class="center_content_index">
    <ul class="ul_1">

        <LiServiceApp
          v-for="i in $store.state.index.dbIndexData.data.activities"
          :item="i"
          :key="i.id">
        </LiServiceApp>

    </ul>
    <!--  <ul class="ul_1"> end -->

  </section>

</template>


<script>

  import LiServiceApp from '~/components/CenterContentIndexApp/LiServiceApp';

  export default{

    data: function(){
      return{

        data1: '',

      }
    },


    components:{
      LiServiceApp,
    },


}
</script>
```

Вопрос: 
Ранее в качестве имени корневого хранилища я использовал IndexPage.js и при подключении к объектам хранилища я обращался так же через это имя - у меня все работало без сбоев.
Но!
Я узнал что такое имя давать не корректно и необходимо что бы оно было именно index.js !
Как только я его изменил соотвествующим образом и изменил путь в подключении к обьектам этого хранилища(на слово index вместо IndexPage) - я получил ошибку такого плана:
Так же мне пришлось поменять fetch на dispatch в некоторых местать и добавить actions.

[image: http://joxi.ru/Y2LlMPYC7kKJ82]
[image: http://joxi.ru/52aXbPzUEVPq5m]

Есть у кого нибудь какие то идеи почему не работает данная страница в текущей конфигурации и как исправить положение вещей на ней?

Comment: К содержимому стор лучше обращаться через геттеры, это во-первых. Монтирование компонента явно происходит раньше инициализации модуля вьюекс, это во-вторых. Данные в сторе должны инициализироваться так, как написано в справке (со всеми свойствами, использующимися в рендеринге, а не `null`), это в-третьих.

Comment: @yar85, на счет пункта 3: null это не undefined, поэтому, вполне допустимое значение

Comment: так а что делать тогда - может кто нибудь подсказать - какой синтаксис будет корректен в данном случае?
https://github.com/Mike-Kharkov/mike_kharkov_repositiry/tree/Mike-Kharkov-patch-1
Работающий код с названием корневого хранилища indexPage.js
Может кто нибудь преобразование попробовать сделать с изменением названия корневого файла и что бы не было ошибок в итоге?

Comment: @Дмытрык, спасибо за уведомление о несогласии, это крайне полезная информация.